# Set the selected text or value for a KendoDropDownList

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm using Durandal and Kendo UI. My current problem is the edit popup event on my grid. I cannot seem to set the selected value on my dropdown.

I can debug and inspect, and I indeed do see the correct value of e.model.InstrumentName nicely populated.

How can I set the value/text of those dropdowns in edit mode ?

Here's my grid init:

```
      positGrid = $("#positGrid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: datasource,         
        columnMenu: false,
        {
            field: "portfolioName", title: "Portfolio Name",
            editor: portfolioDropDownEditor, template: "#=portfolioName#"      
        },
        {
            field: "InstrumentName",
            width: "220px",
            editor: instrumentsDropDownEditor, template: "#=InstrumentName#",
        },
        edit: function (e) {
            var instrDropDown = $('#InstrumentName').data("kendoDropDownList");
            var portfDropDown = $('#portfolioName').data("kendoDropDownList");
            instrDropDown.list.width(350);  // let's widen the INSTRUMENT dropdown list

            if (!e.model.isNew()) {          // set to current valuet                
                //instrDropDown.text(e.model.InstrumentName); // not working...
                instrDropDown.select(1);
                //portfDropDown.text();
            }
        },
          filterable: true,
        sortable: true,
        pageable: true,
        editable: "popup",
    });
```

Here's my Editor Template for the dropdown:

function instrumentsDropDownEditor(container, options) {

```
    // INIT INSTRUMENT DROPDOWN !
    var dropDown = $('<input id="InstrumentName" name="InstrumentName">'); 
    dropDown.appendTo(container);
    dropDown.kendoDropDownList({
        dataTextField: "name",
        dataValueField: "id",
        dataSource: {
            type: "json",
            transport: {
                read: "/api/breeze/GetInstruments"
            },                    
        },
        pageSize: 6,
        select: onSelect,
        change: function () { },
        optionLabel: "Choose an instrument"
    }).appendTo(container);


}
```

thanks a lot
Bob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your editor configuration is bit unlucky for grid, anyway i have updated my ans on provided code avoiding manual selections:

**Assumptions**: Instrument dropdown editor only (leaving other fields as strings), Dummy data for grid

```
<div id="positGrid"></div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {    

        $("#positGrid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                data: [
              { PositionId: 1, Portfolio: "Jane Doe", Instrument: { IID: 3, IName: "Auth2" }, NumOfContracts: 30, BuySell: "sfsf" },
            { PositionId: 2, Portfolio: "John Doe", Instrument: { IID: 2, IName: "Auth1" }, NumOfContracts: 33, BuySell: "sfsf" }
                ],
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: "PositionId",
                        fields: {
                            "PositionId": { type: "number" },
                            Portfolio: { validation: { required: true } },
                            Instrument: { validation: { required: true } },
                            NumOfContracts: { type: "number", validation: { required: true, min: 1 } },
                            BuySell: { validation: { required: true } }
                        }
                    }
                }    
            },
            toolbar: [
                { name: "create", text: "Add Position" }
            ],
            columns: [
                { field: "PositionId" },
                { field: "Portfolio" },
                { field: "Instrument", width: "220px",
                    editor: instrumentsDropDownEditor, template: "#=Instrument.IName#" },
                { field: "NumOfContracts" },
                { field: "BuySell" },
                { command: [ "edit", "destroy" ]
            },
            ],
            edit: function (e) {
                var instrDropDown = $('#InstrumentName').data("kendoDropDownList");                
                instrDropDown.list.width(400);  // let's widen the INSTRUMENT dropdown list                
            },
            //sortable: true,
            editable: "popup",
        });
    });

    function instrumentsDropDownEditor(container, options) {
        $('<input id="InstrumentName" required data-text-field="IName" data-value-field="IID" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
            .appendTo(container)
            .kendoDropDownList({                                
                dataSource: {
                    type: "json",
                    transport: {
                        read: "../Home/GetMl"
                    }
                },
                optionLabel:"Choose an instrument"
            });
    }
</script>
```

Action fetching json for dropddown in Home controller:

```
public JsonResult GetMl()
        {
            return Json(new[] { new { IName = "Auth", IID = 1 }, new { IName = "Auth1", IID = 2 }, new { IName = "Auth2", IID = 3 } }, 
                JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: not working. I've updated my code above to show the editor template function. I can't even use standard jquery to update the dropdown value - i.e. $("#instrDropDown").val("test")

Comment: NB: instrDropDown.select(2) actually does the dropdown selected value BUT ONLY AS I DEBUG. As soon as I leave the grid EDIT event my dropdown list goes back to "Choose an instrument". What gives ? Please help. thank you.

Comment: Hello binbsr. I've in turn updated your answer by adding a Kendo DataSource. I understand how your setup Instrument: { IID: 3, IName: "Auth2" } but how do I translate that into my datasource schema ? thanks again. Bob.

Comment: Just return the convenient json for your grid from the API. Can you show me what your api returning? In your api get, just create some viewmodels, bind some data and finally convert to json for your grid.

Comment: I just updated your answer to show my json data sample. i would have to ask the other developer to send the Instrument Data as a namepair ID/NAME.

Comment: we got it working inside EDIT event using instrDropDown.value(e.model.instrumentId);

Comment: I already described how dropdown data got remotely binded and templated. In grid data: If Instrument(and others) is coming as foreign key, we may have have to tweak a bit and use [this](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/foreignkeycolumn.html), if this is the normal json object as in my local dadasource then everything should be fine. Anyway you got it work, always happy to hear that.