# Kendo cell values from dropdownlist shows as undefined when not in edit mode

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am working on Kendo UI grid and I was implemented dropdownlist (for edit mode (display popup)). When my grid is load, then always shows 'undefined' value for every cell which use dropdownlist in edit mode. Everything is fine, if I using add/edit mode for insert/update values. I don't know what is wrong with my code. This is part of my code:

```
 columns: [{
            field: "Id",
            title: "Id",
            width: 50
        }, {
            field: "finNaturalBusinessYearId",
            title: "Poslovna godina",
            width: 70,
            template: "#= finNaturalBusinessYearId.NaturalBusinessYear #",
            editor: businessyeardropdown
        },...
```

And function for dropdownlist:

```
function businessyeardropdown(container, options) {
        $('<input required data-text-field="NaturalBusinessYear" data-value-field="Id" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoDropDownList({
            autobind: false,
            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    read:
                    {
                        url: "/api/BusinessYear",
                        type: "GET",
                        dataType: "json"
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Pls help...

Answer (score 0):

It is because object **finNaturalBusinessYearId** does not contain property **NaturalBusinessYear**.

Here is [Dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/afECe/8) - As you can see, If I used property which does not exists, values are displayed as "undefined" but if property exists, value is appeared.

So please check, if

1. *finNaturalBusinessYearId* is an object
2. If it is object than check if contains property *NaturalBusinessYear*

Comment: In my case finNaturalBusinessYearId is a foreign key. In add/edit mode i have properly values. I am using [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Jkkw8/100/) example and similar, such this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19868423/set-the-selected-text-or-value-for-a-kendodropdownlist).

Comment: In both cases you have mentioned it is an object. In first case you have *"Category": { CategoryName: "Condiments", CategoryID: 2 },* and it is why you can write Category.CategoryName into template. 
If *finNaturalBusinessYearId* is foreign key then it is just value (and not object) right?
I don't know how you load data but I expect that by ajax - so try return object which will contains values as your Id and value, then you will be able to write object.Value ...

Comment: In edit mode it is displayed correctly, because dropdown has its own datasource and you are returning list of objects with properties Id and NaturalBusinessYear - and its why it is displayed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think I just had this same problem.
Change this:

```
$('<input required data-text-field="NaturalBusinessYear" data-value-field="Id" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
```

to this:

```
$('<input required data-text-field="finNaturalBusinessYearId" data-value-field="Id" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
```

that way it matches the field name from your datasource